# Windows X to 10 upgrades and future activations

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

As you may be aware, there is a 'free' upgrade to Win10 on until the end of this month.

From what I understand, illegitimate *and* legitimate copies of >Win10 can make the upgrade path, and once upgraded 'Product IDs' are issued based the machines hardware (a unique hash is generated based on mainboard, etc).

Dandy.

However: I am in a position where I have over ten machines on legit Win7 installs, want to get them up to Win10, WILL be upgrading hardware or getting new machines, and don't want to deal with future shenanigans when I user needs to reformat their machine (after the end of the month).

What's the best option here...?

Comment: If you have a Microsoft account, you can do this. Upgrade all of the machines you want to upgrade to 10, then wait for the anniversary update. That update is supposed to have an account license binding. This means that your licenses are bound to your outlook account, as opposed to hardware. After that you can upgrade your build.

Comment: Binding licenses to accounts seems ideal... but I'm a little suspicious if this would happen. Do you happen to have a link explaining this, at it sounds interesting (I'm also curious how it would work, ie: requiring to activate from the machine logged in as that account, etc).

Comment: Furthermore, you can see here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/12440/windows-10-activation (at the bottom FAQ link 'Activating Windows 10 after a hardware configuration change'), it states that only calling their help line is an option after doing a hardware upgrade after doing the Win10 update.

Comment: Once a machine is upgraded to Windows 10, Windows 10 will **automatically** activate on that machine.  If you will be upgrading to new hardware, get that new hardware, with Windows 10.  **What** I describe **DOES NOT** require a Microsoft Account.  I have no idea where "ivanempire" got that its required to link local accounts to your MS account.

Comment: What I've seen are tutorials/examples from various blogs or new outlets that demonstrate activation after hardware changes. An example: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-re-activate-windows-10-after-hardware-change